# Preventing headphone cord from tangling while drumming

Tags: headphones

I have a V-Drum kit with a pair of headphones I'm pretty satisfied with. However, since the audio jack is on the left side of the kit, the cord keeps interfering with my hands when I play.

Is there any kind of solution to this? Some kind of a PL cable extender with an integrated lanyard perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Down your back, inside your shirt.

Tie it round your belt to preserve the necessary spare cable.

Extender as required for overall length, couple of quid from Maplin's etc.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a longer cable / extension is the way to go. Then you can easily place the cable behind your back so your playing isn't affected